# Facebook ios sdk app invite

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, applinks

I generated app link with `facebook: https://fb.me/961027397273550`, but when I try to send invite:

```
    FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
    NSString *urlString = @"https://fb.me/961027397273550";
    content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                             delegate:self];
```

I got this error:

> Missing App Link URL
>   The app link used with this invite does not contain an Android or iOS URL. Developers are required to enter a URL for at least one platform.

Why did thats happened?
Can I create app link page with dynamic iOS scheme on my server?

Comment: hmm, that should work. Are you still consistently getting this error? If so, I'd file a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs.

Comment: HI did you get anything ? I also try but did not get any result.. I make that url but after send Invite did not get any notification on friends wall

Comment: Users wont see the invitations unless there is a **valid App ID** (from iTunes Connect) filled in **in the Facebook App settings**. These users must be assigned as testers/developers/admins to the FB app also.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an applink here:
https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host

the iOS url is a url that cna be used to launch you iOS app - e.g. a schema (app://) used for deeplinking.

Comment: I used that url and its work but notification not shown on my friends Wall. Can you please provide the full example.?